# Synapse Pipeline to copy from Datalakes to DW error

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I'm trying to to import data into the Azure Dedicated SQL Pool from our OnPremis DB SQL Servers from Data Lakes. Some of the tables in OnPremise are multiple gig.

Importing the data from Data Lakes only works if I select the "Enable Staging" option and select our existing datalakes container.

My question is, if the import file is already in Data Lakes, why do we need to select a "Enable Staging" option to import it into the Azure Dedicated SQL Pool (DW)?

Answer (score 0):

To copy data from Data Lake to synapse dedicated pool I followed below procedure:

I created synapse dedicated pool linked service:

[image]

I created linked service for data lake Storage Gen2

[image]

I created pipeline and performed copy activity by creating Data lake Storage Gen2 delimited text dataset as source:

[image]

synapse dedicated pool dataset as source and enabled auto create table

[image]

In the settings page enabled stagging selected the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 linked service.

[image]

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-copy-activity-load-sql-pool) **Enable staging** option applies if your source data is not compatible with PolyBase.

The storage is used for staging the data before it loads into Azure Synapse Analytics by using PolyBase. After the copy is complete, the interim data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 is automatically cleaned up.

I debug the pipeline, it run successfully

[image]

It worked for me kindly check from your end.